# Hide Empty columns

Tags: sql

I got a table with 75 columns,. what is the sql statement to display only the columns with values in in ?

thanks

Comment: That statement does **not exist** - you can hide **rows** of data - but not columns

Comment: If your column has no value in it, why have the column?

Comment: @Joel This situation is so frequent (columns ready for future use, values still not inserted because not available, ...)

Comment: Or columns might turn out empty AFTER filtering by some WHERE criteria.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that a similar statement doesn't exist (in a `SELECT` you can use condition filters only for the rows, not for the columns). But you could try to write a (bit tricky) **procedure**. It must check which are the columns that contains at least one not `NULL`/empty value, using queries. When you get this list of columns just join them in a string with a comma between each one and compose a query that you can run, returning what you wanted.

**EDIT**: I thought about it and I think you can do it with a procedure but under one of these conditions:

- find a way to retrieve column names dynamically in the procedure, that is the **metadata** (I never heard about it, but I'm new with procedures)
- or **hardcode** all column names (loosing generality)

You could collect column names inside an **array**, if stored procedures of your DBMS support arrays (or write the procedure in a programming language like C), and loop on them, making a `SELECT` each time, checking if it's an empty* column or not. If it contains at least one value concatenate it in a **string where column names are comma-separated**. Finally you can make your query with only not-empty columns!

Alternatively to stored procedure you could write a short **program** (eg in Java) where you can deal with a better flexibility.

*if you check for **`NULL`** values it will be simple, but if you check for empty values you will need to manage with each column **data type**... another array with data types?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you write a `SELECT` statement and define which `COLUMNS` you wish to display and then save that QUERY as a `VIEW`.

This will save you the trouble of typing in the column names every time you wish to run that query.

As marc_s pointed out in the comments, there is no select statement to hide columns of data.

Comment: The list would need to be dynamic though as an empty column at View creation time wouldn't necessarily stay that way. I can't imagine why this would ever be needed though.

Comment: @Martin: There is an assumption made to my answer that the OP is inquiring about hiding columns because he does not want to look at particular columns when viewing results. And he already know which columns he wants to hide /or not needed when viewing results.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a pre-parse and dynamically create a statement to do this, but this would be a very inefficient thing to do from a SQL performance perspective. Would strongly advice against what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of this is to just select the relevant columns, which was what I needed personally. A quick search of what we're dealing with in a table

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 10;
```

-> shows 20 columns where im interested in 3 of them. Limit is just to not overflow the console.

```
SELECT column1,column3,colum19 FROM table1 WHERE column3='valueX';
```

It is a bit of a manual filter but it works for what I need.